# How to set up Jest w/ESM to recognize non-cjs modules in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest

Have got a successful jest/esm setup, however occasionally a module is released that specifies both a `main` key (for commonjs) and a `module` key (for ESM) in its `package.json`. This leads to jest errors, for example with the [uuid module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid):

```
/repo/path/node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I can see that `dist/esm-browser/index.js` is the file specified by the `module` key in `package.json`.

How can Jest w/ESM be configured to handle these cases, where stuff in node_modules is ESM?

Jest config:

```
{
    "resetMocks": true,
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testMatch": [
      "**/src/**/*.(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
    ],
    "preset": "ts-jest/presets/default-esm",
    "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "useESM": true
      }
    },
    "globalSetup": "<rootDir>/jest/setup.cjs",
    "globalTeardown": "<rootDir>/jest/teardown.cjs",
    "watchPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/.tmp"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^~/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
      "^~components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1",
      "^~util/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/util/$1",
      "^~types/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/types/$1"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

If `transformIgnorePatterns` doesn't work for some reason, you can solve it with `moduleNameMapper`.

```js
    moduleNameMapper: {
        // '^uuid$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/uuid/dist/index.js',
        '^uuid$': require.resolve('uuid'),
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem and it was fixed the same way as mentioned in this comment: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/812#issuecomment-429420861 in my `jest.config.js`:

```js
// list to add ESM to ignore
const esModules = ['uuid'].join('|');
// ...
module.exports = {
  //...
    transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I like it! But is there a way not to have to specify them all individually?